# Fade class out with delay w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following two functions. One checks for a class and if none found it removes another class. The second function executes the first one with delay. Both work well, but instead of abrupt removal of a class I would like to fade it away gradually. Here's what i have so far. Need to fadeOut .txtCCC.

```
function noExpand() {
    exp = $("#prT span.ui-icon-triangle-1-s").size();
    if (exp == 0) {
      $("#prT td.txtCCC").removeClass("txtCCC");
    }
}

$("#prT span.btn").bind("click",function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        noExpand(); //execute load function
    },1000);
});
```

Can't seem to be able to integrate fadeOut...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible to animate `addClass`, `toggleClass` and `removeClass`. But you need the jQueryUI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass/

```
$("#prT td.txtCCC").removeClass("txtCCC", 1000);
```

Comment: Great, I actually use jQuery UI for something else. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "fade" a class. It's either present, or not. You can, however, animate specific numeric CSS properties. Look at [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut), or [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate). Not knowing what specific styles the `txtCCC` class applies, I can't be much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of the class on the attribute is an all-or-nothing thing, you can't have intermediate steps (which would be required for fade behavior).

What you'd have to do to make this happen is apply the various styles that `txtCCC` applies to the element as *inline* styles, remove the class, and then use `animate` to make those styles slowly convert to the matching values of the element without the class. Non-trivial, to say the least, and esp. if it includes colors and such (which jQuery doesn't animate by default, though there are plugins).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to crossfade the effect of a class in jQuery. You need to use `.fadeOut()` or `.animate()`.

You can however fade the effects of a class using CSS3 transitions: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wya3N/

Only works in modern browsers though.

Comment: Yes, I can't wait for CSS3 to finally become a new standard. Unfortunately IE still does not support it well. I try to use CSS whenever possible.